# Transmit at the 300 MHZ - 400 MHZ range

Tags: android, cellular-network, android-kernel

Is there any piece of hardware in a modern Android phone (Galaxy S5+) that can transmit at the 300-400 MHZ range?

If so does this require cracking the radio ROM or is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: I haven't heard of it yet! I only know that Nokia N8 can transmit at RF.

Comment: Try this question on Android Enthusiasts (http://android.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

It is not only a software problem - you need the hardware to do it ( antenna  , etc ) - you will need to attach some hardware ( over usb-otg, bluetooth, .. )